# Are periodic CNAME redirection problems normal

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, cname

I have a google app engine app being forwarded (via a CNAME) to to the www. subdomain of my custom domain name. (http://diablo3values.com) I set up all of this last night. When I woke up this morning it appeared to be working with everything forwarding as expected, however as of a few min ago the forward stopped working, and now it is sending me back to my old host.  Is this normal?  Can the CNAME redirect periodically not work due to propagation or something like that?

EDIT:
So, a while ago it was correctly forwarding again, and then I tried verifying that my facebook like button was working.  So I liked the site, then went to my facebook and clicked on the link to my site from my profile and it stopped working. Even when I cleared my cache and tried a different browser, it no longer forwarded correctly. Seems pretty strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like DNS-Caching. Just be patient, it should vanish 24hrs after creating that forward.